# Upgrade from D3v5 to D3v6 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sourceEvent')

Tags: d3.js

An upgrade to D3v6 caused my onBrush to fail for my `spectrum.js`, and `d3.min.js` to have issues with "NaN".

My code that is getting flagged with the error for `sourceEvent` is:

```
  }, {
        key: "onBrush",
        value: function onBrush() {
            if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return;

            var s = d3.event.selection || this.brushXScale.range();
            this.spectrumXScale.domain(s.map(this.brushXScale.invert, this.brushXScale));
            this.spectrumVis.select(".axis--x").call(this.spectrumXAxis.scale(this.spectrumXScale));
            this.scaleYAxis();
            this.redraw();
```

I understand `sourceEvent` is no longer used in D3v6, but I'm sure how to resolve that line. I'm learning D3 and trying to upgrade this existing code that was written in 2018.

I tried eliminating the `sourceEvent` to `event` for the line code but that doesn't work/make sense for the current code mentioned.

```
value: function onBrush() {
            if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return;
```

I tried the following from the line above since sourceEvent becomes event

```
value: function onBrush(event) {
            if (d3.event.selection && d3.event.selection.type === "zoom") return;
```

It says it can't read "selection" so it would have to be something else being called.

Comment: You probably need  to refer to the argument of the `onBrush` function - i.e.`event`, rather than `d3.event`. I wouldn't expect there to be an `event.selection` property, though. You might find more information in the [migration to V6 guide](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide).